No obvious neutral in breaker box
Just bought a house built in 1960.  No grounds to outlets, not a big issue, just GFI the circuits.
Bought GFI breakers, for the box.  I identified the circuits that need the GFI breakers.
There are only four wires hooked to the neutral bar and they go to newer romex added to the box and are already GFI'd.

There were about 5 grounds on the ground bar.
Where would the neutrals be?
House is wired wierd as I was going to use GFI outlets, but the one breaker had single wire pairs to each outlet, could disconnect each one and still have power at all the rest of the outlets. Another room had power coming into 2 different outlets, that took a while to determine.

A picture showing the whole panel with the cover off would be helpful.

Given the population of red wires I see, these may be MWBCs, which will have 2 hots per neutral. You need to investigate that further before buying any GFCI breakers.

Red wires are for 220 circuits, stove dryer etc

"I was going to use GFI outlets, but the one breaker had single wire pairs to each outlet" - why would this prevent you from using GFI outlets?

@MadMonty It wouldn't prevent someone from using GFCI receptacles, but it could mean they'd need a lot more of them.  When I moved into my house, I discovered that a bunch of kitchen receptacles were wired in a star pattern (i.e., breaker to junction box, then 5 or 6 cables out to 5 or 6 receptacles), rather than a chain, meaning that I needed several GFCIs rather than just one for the start of a chain. It just makes it more expensive.

Could not see a way to add more than 1 picture, here is a link to the photos on Google  https://photos.app.goo.gl/r9zDuzNuomMPU5RH7

Where would the neutrals be?   The neutrals are the white wires and the black wire with the white tape on it going to the neutral bus. The ground bus appears to be next to it but we'd need to see the entire panel to verify it. There are some bare copper wires that should be ground wires. If you have metal conduit for some of the wires, the conduit could be a ground for those circuits.

The 4 white wires go to 4 romex wires in the bottom.  The other power leads all come in at the bottom right corner of the picture above.  There is no other wires attached to the neutral bar,

the ground bar is on the other side of the breakers,  I WILL try and get a whole picture of the panel tomorrow or Fri.

@davidkardelis  You also have a black wire with white tape on it connected to the neuuutral bus. That it probably your neutral feed to the panel.  The 240 volt circuits may not need a neutral.

THhanks, I figured it was a mis colored wire.  There is another black wire going to the ground on the other side, marked to distinguish it

FInally got back into the box.  I can easily see the neutral coming in.  I see 2 (8 ga maybe)large bare copper ground wires( they are connectedto ground) going into the same hole all the power wires are  entering.  I am thinking they took the round to a junction box somewhere and connected the neutrals in the box to those.

I have pictures but do not see a way to add them to the thread. Any help on that front.
